# Добавление в массив

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, надо объединять массивы через цикл foreach, есть такой массив

```
$products = [1:[name: rose, product_id: 1, price: 199],
             2:[name: tulip, product_id: 2, price: 299]..]
```

и есть вот такой второй массив:

```
$sizes = [1:[name: 50cm, product_id: 1, price: 20],
          2:[name: 60cm, product_id: 1, price: 30],
          3:[name: 50cm, product_id: 2, price: 10],
          4:[name: 60cm, product_id: 2, price: 15]..]
```

Первый массив $products создается таким образом

```
$products = array();
foreach($array as $product) {
    $item[$product['product_id']] = array("name" => $product['name'], "product_id" => $product['product_id'], "price" => $product['price']);
    $products += $item;
}
```

Второй массив таким:

```
$sizes = array();
foreach($array2 as $size) {
    $item[$size['id']] = array("name" => $size['name'], "product_id" => $size['product_id'], "price" => $size['price']);
    $sizes += $item;
}
```

Нужно чтобы получился такой массив

```
$results = [1:[name: rose, product_id: 1, price: 199, size: [1:[name: 50cm, product_id: 1, price: 20],2:[name: 60cm, product_id: 1, price: 30]]],
            2:[name: tulip, product_id: 2, price: 299], size: [3:[name: 50cm, product_id: 2, price: 10],4:[name: 60cm, product_id: 2, price: 15]]]
```

Спасибо заранее

Comment: А почему именно через цикл? Можно ж использовать `array_merge()`?

Comment: а как проверку запускать? там же еще надо проверять product_id

Comment: Опишите подробно алгоритм слияния массивов.

Comment: Во втором массиве $sizes имеется значение product_id, оно должно соответствовать значениям product_id массива $products